# How can I make this algorithm more efficient for a puzzle?

Tags: python, timeout, puzzle

The puzzle is: given a number `n`, I need to return an array containing all numbers whose sum of their squares equals `n^2` in a increasing sequence. For example: `[3,4]` is a valid solution since `3^2 + 4^2 = 25`, but for `n = 50`, `[1, 1, 4, 49]` wouldn't because `1, 1` is not an increasing sequence. The test also mentions that, should two or more sequences be valid, we should choose the one with the biggest final number. If no solution was found, it should return `None`.
Then, I made this code, which managed to pass the two preliminary tests where `n` was `5` and `8`, but timed out in the bigger tests, which is nothing but predictable. So, how can I make it more efficient? I was thinking of using a generator, but can't decide where:

```
def decompose(n):
    add = []
    result = []
    for i in range (n-1, 0, -1):
        if sum(add) < n ** 2:
            add.append(i**2)
            result.append(i)
        elif sum(add) > n ** 2:
            add.pop()
            result.pop()
        elif sum(add) == n ** 2:
            return sorted(result)
    return None
```

Comment: Is there a requirement that the array have a length greater than 1?  If not, you could simply return `[n]`, which is a constant-time solution.  (or did you mean that the sum of squares should be `n`, not `n**2`?  the `n2` is ambiguous.)

Comment: Speed isn't the problem, the code doesn't work. I gave it n=50 (which should have solution [30, 40]) but it returns None.

Comment: Yes, there is a requirement that [n] or [1,1,1...1] won't work. Also, 50 must return [1, 3, 5, 8, 49] or so because 49 is the highest number it can work, so [30, 40] shouldn't be valid. It realy doesn't work, though.

Comment: Yes you're right about the solution for 50, I was just giving an example of one that worked. The main point is that you shouldn't be trying to optimise your code for speed when it doesn't work at all. I have a 12 lines solution, but one that requires recursion. I'm happy to provide it, but as this is clearly homework, perhaps you want a better go at it yourself first?

Comment: It's not homework, but rather a training to sharpen my skills. I'm a self-taught software developer. I will take the recursion tip, though.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting, I'll post my solution below then for inspiration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not optimised for speed but it does give the correct solution. The trick is to use recursion. The critical variable for this problem is not only n itself, but also the sum that the elements in the list must have. Initially this is n**2, but every time you add a new element the left over sum lowers, and so does the largest integer that you can add to the list afterwards. Thus, adding a new number to the list is just the old problem again, but with different constraints. This makes this a recursive problem and a brilliant example of when to use `yield` and `yield from`.

```
def decompose(max_n, sum_allowed, solution):
    for x in range(max_n, 0, -1):
        left_over_sum = sum_allowed - x**2
        if left_over_sum == 0:
            yield [x] + solution
        elif left_over_sum > 0:
            yield from decompose(x-1, left_over_sum, [x] + solution)
    yield None

def decompose_top(n):
    generator = decompose(n-1, n**2, [])
    return next(generator)

print(decompose_top(1000001))
```

On this 7 year old machine I can easily go to n=100000 with only a second of execution time. By calling next() on the generator multiple times, one could see all possible solutions for a given n.